# Given a set of non orthogonal functions. Find another set of functions that are orthogonal to the first set.

Tags: orthogonality, eigenfunctions

Let's say I have a set of complex functions $\{\phi_1,\phi_2,...\}$ defined on $0\leq x \leq1$, and they are not orthogonal i.e. $\int_0^1\phi_m^*(x) \phi_n(x)dx \neq \delta_{mn}$. Is it possible to find another set of functions $\{\psi_1,\psi_2,...\}$ that satisfy the orthogonality property i.e. $\int_0^1\psi_m^*(x) \phi_n(x)dx = \delta_{mn}$? Alternatively is it possible to find a weight function that makes the first set of functions orthogonal $\int_0^1 w(x) \phi_m^*(x) \phi_n(x)dx = \delta_{mn}$. For concreteness I'm looking at the functions $\phi_n(x)=\cosh((\alpha_n+i\omega_n)x)$, where $\omega_n=(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\tanh(\alpha_n)=1-\frac{J_1(0.002\omega_n)}{0.002\omega_n}$.

I'm pretty sure this can be done with a modification of the Gram-Schmidt process, but I'm hoping to find a non iterative solution.

Answer (score 1):

See the Gram-Schmidt process:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm leaning towards or rather some modification of it. I was hoping to find a non iterative solution.

Comment: If your functions have special properties (like the exp and trig functions that give the Fourier series), you might be able to. In general, no.

Comment: What sort of special properties? I'm working with hyperbolic cosines, so they have nice derivative properties.

Comment: They are always positive over the reals, so getting them to be orthogonal might be interesting.

Comment: Well they're complex hyperbolic cosines. So they do [oscillate](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cosh%28%28i*3*pi%2F2%2B0.5%29x%29).

Comment: Then they involve complex exps, so you might have a chance. Propose it as a problem.

Comment: If the set of functions are lin. indep. Then we could start with a function g not in the span and write $f(x)=g(x)-\sum a_n\phi_n(x)\Rightarrow \int f(x)\phi_m(x)dx=\int g(x)\phi_m(x)dx-\sum_n \int\phi_n(x)\phi_m(x)dx a_n=0$ which is a matrix inversion problem to find the $a_n$.